# How can I easily host a CGI executable (.exe) file locally on windows

Tags: windows, cgi, exe

I have been able to make Common Gateway Interface (CGI) executables work in IIS / IIS express in the past, but its a real faff and always takes a lot of trawling through the internet and trying lots of things, and it seems to change a bit in each version of IIS.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python installed, you can run this from the command line:

`python -m http.server --cgi 8000`

You will need to run it in the directory that the website is in, and the CGI executable should be in a `cgi-bin` sub directory. More details on the [Python Website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)

If you haven't got Python installed, it is probably easier to install it, than it is to get IIS working.